# Playing with strings in C

Tags: c, string, input, char, scanf

Below is the input of a file I am taking as **standard input through redirection** for a C program. How can I **skip lines** starting from `>` and `$` and taking input like that of starting from `MNLQRF..` in a *string* which will be of **dynamic length**?

```
>pair 1
MNLQRFPRHPLTFGPTPIQPLKRLSAHLGGQVELYAKREDCNSGLAFGGNKTRKLEYLIP
EALAQGCDTLVSIGGIQSNQTRQVAAVAAHLGMKCVLVQENWVNYSDAVYDRVGNIEMSR
ILGADVRLDAAGFDIGIRPSWEQAMADVRAAGGKPFPIPAGCSEHRLGGLGFVGFAEEVR
AQEAELGFKFDYIVVCSVTGSTQAGMVVGFAADGRAERVIGIDASAKPEQTHAQILRIAQ
NTAELVGLGREITAQDVVLDTRYGGPEYGLPSEGTLEAIRLCARQEGMLTDPVYEGKSMH
GMIDKVKRGEFPAGSRVLYAHLGGVPALNAYSFLFRNG
$
MMRGFKQRLIKKTTGSSSSSSSKKKDKEKEKEKSSTTSSTSKKPASASSSSHGTTHSSAS
STGSKSTTEKGKQSGSVPSQGKHHSSSTSKTKTATTPSSSSSSSRSSSVSRSGSSSTKKT
SSRKGQEQSKQSQQPSQSQKQGSSSSSAAIMNPTPVLTVTKDDKSTSGEDHAHPTLLGAV
SAVPSSPISNASGTAVSSDVENGNSNNNNMNINTSNTQDANHASSQSIDIPRSSHSFERL
PTPTKLNPDTDLELIKTPQRHSSSRFEPSRYTPLTKLPNFNEVSPEERIPLFIAKVDQCN
TMFDFNDPSFDIQGKEIKRSTLDELIEFLVTNRFTYTNEMYAHVVNMFKINLFRPIPPPV
NPVGDIYDPDEDEPVNELAWPHMQAVYEFFLRFVESPDFNHQIAKQYIDQDFILKLLELF
DSEDIRERDCLKTTLHRIYGKFLSLRSFIRRSMNNIFLQFIYETEKFNGVAELLEILGSI
INGFALPLKEEHKVFLVRILIPLHKVRCLSLYHPQLAYCIVQFLEKDPLLTEEVVMGLLR
YWPKINSTKEIMFLNEIEDIFEVIEPLEFIKVEVPLFVQLAKCISSPHFQVAEKVLSYWN
NEYFLNLCIENAEVILPIIFPALYELTSQLELDTANGEDSISDPYMLVEQAINSGSWNRA
IHAMAFKALKIFLETNPVLYENCNALYLSSVKETQQRKVQREENWSKLEEYVKNLRINND
KDQYTIKNPELRNSFNTASENNTLNEENENDCDSEIQ
$$
```

So it will be like just read `MNLQRF..` and `MMRGFKQ..` into two different strings ingnoring all other noise data.
Help please!!

Comment: Write some code a come back with a particular problem with that code. We are not here to write the code for you. BTW if you are developer by blood - prove it

Comment: Haha.. I liked the taunt. Wait! Will share what I have wrote can work.

Answer (score 2):

Start reading file each line using [fgets()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets), strip leading and any trailing white spaces. If the first character is a `>` & `$` then continue reading next line.

EDIT:

```
char input[100]; // YOu can decide on the size of line
if (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin) == NULL) {
  ;  // handle EOF
}
```

Comment: Same doubt. This is a standard input. How will fgets work? It has file pointer in its parameter, right?

Comment: Will fgets(buffer, size, stdin) work?

Comment: Worked. Thanks :) Though, it is shameful to ask such doubts. I am enjoying this forum as it has really talented people in it to assist at deadlocks :)

Comment: @DeveloperbyBlood Yes. But look at the answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

1. Read each line using `fgets()` (or optionally `readline()` on a POSIX system).
2. Look at the first character of the line that was read and decide whether to pay attention or not.

There is no standard C function that will skip lines based on the first character of the line.

Comment: But this is a standard input. How will fgets work? It has file pointer in its parameter, right?

Comment: Use `fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin)` to use `fgets()` to read from `stdin` (aka standard input).  You could use `fprintf(stdout, ...)` to print to standard output, though that would usually be regarded as perverse, but you have to use `fprintf(stderr, ...)` to print to standard error.  The situation with standard input is analogous.